# Facebook sdk javascript fetching user data

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm currently building an application which requires users to log in with their facebook account. Next I want the user's birthday, location, first- and lastname. To get the user's name isn't a problem but the location and birthday is not working properly.

I'm scoping to ask the user for permission to access his/her data:

> function loginUser() {
>        FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'user_birthday,user_location'});
>        }

And next I want to write the user's location to the console just for testing:

> function testAPI() {
>       FB.api('/me?fields=user_location', function(response) {
>         console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.user_location + '.');
>       });

Any idea's how to get this data?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`user_birthday` and `user_location` are the names of the permissions, not the field names; these are `birthday` and `location`. The following works for me:

```
function testAPI() { 
    FB.api('/me?fields=birthday,location', 
           function(response) { 
               console.log('Good to see you, user from ' + response.location + '.'); 
           });
}
```

Comment: hmm console says: Good to see you, user from [object Object].

Comment: Instead of `response.location` you should use `response.location.name` to get the location's name.